# C# Class Initialize and set data and List information

Tags: c#, class, initialization

I am able to set the values for each item in ROOT, such as Address_to and Line_items, but when I try to pass the populated class to Post, it's empty.

```
public class OrdersClass
{
    public class Line_items
    {
        public string sku { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }

    }
    public class Address_to
    {
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string address1 { get; set; }
        public string address2 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string zip { get; set; }

    }
    public class Root
    {
        public string external_id { get; set; }
        public IList<Line_items> line_items { get; set; }
        public Address_to address_to { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My c# code:

```
 OrdersClass.Root thisOrder = new OrdersClass.Root();
 
 thisOrder.address_to = new OrdersClass.Address_to();

 IList<OrdersClass.Line_items> lineItems = new List<OrdersClass.Line_items>();
```

I can populate address_to as

```
  thisOrder.address_to.first_name  "my first name";
```

and line_items using:
lineItems.Add(new OrdersClass.Line_items());

```
 lineItems[0].sku = ProductSKU;
 lineItems[0].quantity = cartQuantity;
```

but..I know I'm doing this wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: You've created a list object but you haven't added anything to it.  Create instances of `OrdersClass.LineItems,` set their properties and add them to the list via the `Add` function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `Line_items`:

```
IList<OrdersClass.Line_items> lineItems = new List<OrdersClass.Line_items>();

var lineItem1 = new OrdersClass.Line_items()
{
    quantity = 1,
    sku = "sku1"
};
lineItems.Add(lineItem1);

var lineItem2 = new OrdersClass.Line_items()
{
    quantity = 2,
    sku = "sku2"
};
lineItems.Add(lineItem2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
lineitems.Add(new OrderClass.Line_items(){
  sku = ProductSKU,
  quantity = cartQuantity
});
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to show my code for adding line_item.  I did have a capital letter error in Line _item vs line_item.  I do like Daniel's format. 
So now...I am getting an error:  Object not set to an instance:
       thisOrder.line_items.Add(new OrdersClass.Line_items() {
                sku = printifyProductSKU,
                quantity = cartQuantity
            });   
Note: I added: thisOrder. to line_items.

Comment: Set default constructor for avoid it. Like this:

    public class Root
    {
        public string external_id { get; set; }
        public IList<Line_items> line_items { get; set; }
        public Address_to address_to { get; set; }
        
        public Root()
        {
            this.external_id = string.Empty;
            this.address_to = new Address_to();
            this.line_items = new List<Line_items>();
        }
    }

but careful for recursive

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who helped me get my thinking cap back on. Resolved.
line_items.Add did not add the iList to the main "thisOrder" class.
I had instantianted it syntactically correct, but it programmatically correct.
This worked:

```
thisOrder.line_items = new List<OrdersClass.Line_items>();
```

Then adding a new ilist:

```
var lineItem = new OrdersClass.Line_items()
        {
            quantity = cartQuantity,
            sku = printifyProductSKU
        };
        thisOrder.line_items.Add(lineItem);
```

Yea. Now on the to the programming challenge:ASYNC Post vs Put.
Thanks.